# what does "sharpen profile against something/someone" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Here is the sentence: "each definition of biopolitics must sharpen its analytical and critical profile against the blind spots and weak points of competing suggestions."

Comment: Which specific aspect of the text confuses you? It's all a bit "flowery", and for my money it steers perilously close to "mixed metaphors", but it's still essentially "English".

Answer (score 1):

Sharpen in this context means to make better. It's a metaphor that comes from the act of sharpening knives. You sharpen a knife when it's dull *to make it perform better.* There's an even better word you can use: **hone**.

> **Hone**
>   1. Sharpen (a blade).
>   2. Refine or perfect (something) over a period of time.
>   *"She has spent countless hours at the keyboard, honing her skills."*

Here sharpen means the same thing.

Comment: I'd extend the metaphor a little: i think it's not just about sharpening your knife, it's about **sharpening your knife in order to exploit an opponent's weak spots"**.  Ie, the metaphor is about preparing your weapons **for battle** (as opposed to cooking, for example).  The competing suggestions are the opponents in this metaphor.

Answer (score 0):

Superpentil is on the mark for the use of sharpen in this case, in that it means "to make better".

Usually one uses a tool to sharpen, for instance a [whetstone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharpening_stone), which is specifically designed to sharpen a knife.

Taken together, the metaphor is suggesting that these "blind spots and weaknesses" should be seen as a tool for making the "definitions of biopolitics" better.